# posting string data back via webservice using ajax and jquery

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, jquery

all,

I'm trying to pass html data up to a webservice that exists in .NET/c#.  I'm using JQUERY but continue to get an error of "failed posted data".  Is my syntax wrong in either my ajax script or in my code behind?  Thanks for any help.

```
$(function () {

    $("[id$=rdbSaveAjax]").click(function () {  

    var markedUPHTML = $("[id$=wrapper]").html();
    var postData = "{'HTMLData' : '" + markedUPHTML + "'}";

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Role.asmx/test",
            data: JSON.stringify({html: postData}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("successfully posted data");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("failed posted data");
                alert(JSON.stringify(postData));
            }

        }); 
    });

});
```

webservice code behind:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Role
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Role : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string test(string html)
    {

        string strHTMLData = html;
        return html;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all,

I ended up finding the issue by using firebug.  Everytime I tried posting back to connect to the test method in my Role.asmx file, I would get a 500 error.  My solution is a Cassini project so I could not do much with configuring my local IIS site to change permissions.

Instead, I created a method in my code behind and placed [WebMethod] right above the method name.  In my code behind I did not setup any declarations that you would typically see after adding a webservice file to your solution.

[WebMethod]
   public static bool test(string strHTMLMarkup)
   {
        ....code
   }

I hope this helps anyone other there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`var postData = "{'HTMLData' : '" + markedUPHTML + "'}";`

This will not build a proper string if `markedUPHTML` has single or double quote in it. Use `JavaScript` `escape` method before concatenating. Try this

`var postData = "{'HTMLData' : '" + escape(markedUPHTML) + "'}";`

And then while passing the data you dont have to `strigify` it because its already a `string`. Just try this

```
 data: { html: postData }
```

Comment: Thank you ShankarSangoli, however, I tend to get the same error.  You solution does make sense though.

Answer (score 0):

Try public static string on the server side, instead of public string

Comment: I added static to my method but still no luck.

Comment: Okay, what's the exact error message and how are you finding it?. Use a browser Console to and read the requests/responses. It's either failing because an internal error in the service, can't find Role.asmx or something else.